# Why isn't my authentication working? (Apex)

Tags: authentication, oracle-apex

I have a function to authenticate my users, which works because I tested it.

Authenticate function:

```
create or replace function authenticate(p_username in VARCHAR2, p_password in VARCHAR2) 
return BOOLEAN 
is 
  l_password varchar2(4000); 
  l_stored_password varchar2(4000); 
  l_count number; 
begin 
select count(*) into l_count from users where username = p_username; 
if l_count > 0 then 
  -- First, we fetch the stored hashed password
  select password into l_stored_password 
   from users where upper(username) = upper(p_username); 
    -- we have to apply the custom hash function to the password 
    l_password := custom_hash(p_username, p_password); 
    -- Finally, we compare them to see if they are the same and return
    -- either TRUE or FALSE
    if l_password = l_stored_password then 
      return true; 
    else 
      return false; 
    end if; 
else 
  -- The username provided is not in the users table
  return false; 
end if; 
end;
```

Yet my authentication in Apex doesn't work, I activated the authentication scheme and linked to authenticate function. 
I'm using apex 4.2

Comment: You've placed this code in the "PLSQL Code" under "Source" in the authentication scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've got mine setup:

Scheme Type: Custom
Authentication Function Name: my_auth_func
Source:

```
FUNCTION my_auth_func (p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
    is_authenticated BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
    --authentication logic, etc...
    RETURN is_authenticated;
END
```